# How do I create a code that will log either YES or NO. can somebody make this for me? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

How do I create a code that will log either YES or NO. can somebody make this for me? (Javascript)
I have tried using

```
console.log(Math.round(Math.random))
```

but that doesn't work. any similar coin flip like randomiser would work too.

Comment: Welcome. Have a quick look at "How do I ask a good question?" https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is you're aren't calling `Math.random`.

```js
console.log(Math.round(Math.random()) ? "YES": "NO")
```

Alternatively, you can check if `Math.random()` is greater than `0.5` or not.

```js
console.log(Math.random() > 0.5 ? "YES": "NO")
```

Comment: Thank You!, That Worked. I'm Sorry if the question seemed so basic because I have only been coding for 2 days.

Comment: @THEREALKEEGANWELCH Consider going through the link mentioned in the comments above. Also, if this solved your problem consider accepting this as an answer to mark your issue resolved (you can do so by clicking on the check mark next to the answer).